# Google Sheet Query - Group / concatenate multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm running a `QUERY` with a `SUM` and `GROUP BY`, but I'd like to aggregate multiple distinct values from the rows into a single row and column. I'm looking to concatenate all those values together.

**Current Table:**

| Person | Widget | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | Red | 12 |
| Bill | Blue | 9 |
| Sarah | Yellow | 4 |
| Bill | Yellow | 1 |
| Sarah | Orange | 10 |

**Expected Table**:

| Person | Widget | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | Red, Blue, Yellow | 22 |
| Sarah | Yellow, Orange | 14 |

Comment: Using a script would be easier, sql doesn't have a method for returning multiple records as one...

Answer (score 20):

You can use the filter and join functions to help:

To get a unique list of names:

```
=UNIQUE(A3:A)
```

To join the widgets:

```
=join(",",filter(B:B,A:A=E3))
```

To sum the values:

```
=sum(filter(C:C,A:A=E3))
```

[image]

Comment: Anyway to make the JOIN and SUM an array formula? So as new Person, Widget and Count is added, the table updates automatically?

Comment: This is amazing. I wish Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel could add this in their Pivot table's summary function, just like Splunk.