Google Sheet formula for concatenation



Names
Value




Jack
A2


Jack
A3


Jack
A4


Tom
A5


Tom
A6



How can I join all values in "Value" column in one cell that map to each name in Column Names?  Also, have another column that counts the total values in each cell for Column Values?
Example:



Names
Value




Jack
A2 A3 A4


Tom
A5 A6




See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048134/google-sheet-query-group-concatenate-multiple-rows/36510387#36510387

Use the following formula-
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A6),MAP(UNIQUE(A2:A6),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=x)))))


